# Android Animation Starting Position

Tags: android, animation

I have a chat client that looks similar to Google Hangouts.  At the bottom I have a edittext box for the message entry and to the right I have the send button.  I can animate the send button based on if the user has text in the message box using addTextChangedListener.  But the initial position of the send button should be off screen because the user has not entered any text yet.  Once the user enters text, the send button should slide in from the right.  I need help to figure out how to initially position the send button off screen and animate it onto the screen next to the message edittext.

To animate the Send button, I used property animators ...

send.animate().xBy( -send.getWidth() ).setDuration( 1000 );

Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to use ObjectAnimators, then you can simply use the static methods that are used to create one.

```
Object target = send
int from = -send.getWidth()
int to = 0
ObjectAnimator slider = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "x", from, to);
slider.setDuration(1000)
slider.start()
```

The initial position can be placed manually by simply calling `send.setX(-send.getWidth())` directly, or setting the Visiblity to View.Invisible initially and then setting to View.Visible in an AnimationListener.

EDIT:

If you need to use the size, you can post a `Runnable` to the View, and it will run as soon as the View is in place.

```
send.post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      int from = -send.getWidth()
      int to = 0
      ObjectAnimator slider = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(send, "x", from, to);
      slider.setDuration(1000)
      slider.start()
   }
});
```

There is a small chance that the View my flash visible before this fires.  To fix that you can set it's initial Visibility to `View.INVISIBLE`, then set it to `View.VISIBLE` in the `Runnable`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the initial width is always 0 of any view.  So I can't use the SetX() method.

Comment: The send.post() worked well for me.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: what about for viewpropertyanimator??